# Are a series of row updates atomic (L2S data context)? If not, how can I make them so?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

I have a Save() method that saved rows using a Linq2Sql DataContext.

```
    private void Save(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Validate();
        selectNumUnitsByPidCdCostRevBindingSource.EndEdit();
        var db = new AccountingDataClassesDataContext(true);
        unitCountDataSet
            .GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified).Tables[0].Rows
            .Cast<EomApp1.Formss.Accounting.Data.UnitCountDataSet.SelectNumUnitsByPidCdCostRevRow>().ToList()
            .ForEach(row =>
            {
                db.Items.First(item => item.id == row.id).num_units = row.num_units;
            });
        db.SubmitChanges();
        Fill();
    }
```

This is the first time I've ever really wanted to ensure multiple updates occurred as a single batch (all or nothing) - and I'm just not sure if result of SubmitChanges() will be so.

If the answer is no, then what is the way to put this into a transaction?

Comment: Not relevant to the question exactly - but assuming this is real code - where do you dispose/close the context?  You should probably use a using() block.

Comment: thanks.  yes, its real - i didn't think it was necessary (can't tell you why that is) - is there a real resource leak here or it's proper to put anything that implements disposable in a using block?

Comment: hmmm... looking at some stuff it appears maybe it's not necessary from a connection management perspective. However - I'd always dispose a disposable just for good practice. But I think you're correct there is no leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SubmitChanges() call will create a new transaction if one does not already exist, so yes these changes will be atomic.

Basically you're in the third case as described in these docs:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386995(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386995%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)